# How to properly create an array in ARM assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm

I'm currently learning ARM assembly for a class and have come across a problem where I'd need to use an "array." I'm aware that there is no such thing as an array in ARM so I have to allocate space and treat that as an array. I have two questions.

1. Am I correctly adding new values to the array or am I merely overwriting the previous value? If I am overwriting the values, how do I go about adding new values?
2. How do I go about looping through the different values of the array? I know I have to use `loop:` but don't know how to use it to access different "indexes."

So far, this is what I've gotten from reading ARM documentation as I've gathered from resources online.

```
        .equ SWI_Exit,  0x11

        .text
        .global _start

_start: .global _start
        .global main

        b       main

main:
        ldr     R0, =MyArray
        mov     R1, #42
        str     R1, [R0], #4
        mov     R1, #43
        str     R1, [R0], #4
        swi     SWI_Exit

MyArray: .skip 20 * 4
        .end
```

As a side note, I am using [ARMSim#](http://armsim.cs.uvic.ca/) as required by my professor, so some commands recognized by GNU tools won't be recognized by ARMSim#, or at least I believe that is the case. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why the down vote? Yes, this is a partially related to homework but I can see this information being useful to others and I'm not asking how to do my assignment.

Comment: If you want to state it that way there is no such thing as an array in any processor family not just arm.  Arrays dont actually exist, they are just a blob of memory that start somewhere.  Many instruction sets, definitely arm, support a register offset addressing mode that allows you to get a pure feel of an array.  I would be careful making the statement you made in the future.

Comment: @dwelch Ah thank you for the note, helped a lot with my understanding. I'll also keep in mind not to call them an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are just overwriting elements.  At this level there are "such things as arrays", but only fixed-sized, preallocated arrays.  The `.skip` is allocating the fixed-size array.*  A variable-sized, growable array would typically be implemented with more complex dyanamic memory allocation code using the stack or a heap.
2. If you had a label like `loop:` (the actual name is arbitrary) you could branch (back) to it by using `b loop`.  (Probably, you would want to do the branch conditionally so that the program didn't loop forever.)  You can access different elements in the loop by changing `R0`, which you are already doing

Also the `b main` isn't really serving any purpose since it is branching to he next instruction.  The code will do the same thing if you remove it.

[*] Alternately, you could say that your array is the just elements between `MyArray` and `R0` (not including the memory `R0` points to), in which, by changing `R0` you are extending the array.  But the maximum size Is still fixed by the `.skip` directive.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, didn't realize that `loop:` was arbitrary. Quick question, how would I go about accessing different elements?

Comment: Probably you want to point `R0` at MyArray (e.g. `ldr R0,=MyArray` or `adr R0, MyArray`) then do things like `str rx, [R0, #4]` or `str rx, [R0, R2]` where `R2` has values like 0, 4, 8, ...